# Is there any harm in using RSS.php (or other deprecated features)?

Tags: rss, deprecation, simplepie

I'm using RSS.php to parse RSS feeds on my site because I haven't got my head around SimplePie yet.

Functionally, it works exactly as I want it to, but with error reporting on, I of course get the "RSS.php has been deprecated" error message.

My question is, is there any harm in using RSS.php? I can't find any information on why it was deprecated, and as SimplePie has ceased development, I don't see any pressing need to switch to it.

Comment: Generally there is no harm I would say, but it *has been deprecated*, which could very lead to it not longer being part of WordPress, this would of course would be your harm, using something that will not work with upcoming updates.

Comment: Using deprecaited functions is very risky. What if the core developers decide today that tommorow they delete all depreciated functionality from core in one go without prior notice. You will sit with a broken website and a lot of crap to debug the issue :-)

Comment: Fair enough. Let's crack open SimplePie...

Comment: What is actual issue with Simple Pie. Where are you stuck and errors are you getting. Edit your question or start a new one with this very specific issue. :-)

Comment: [fetch_feed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) together with [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/start#simplepie_item) replaced `fetch_rss` so using some which is deprecated is not the way to go/to ignore as already mentioned by the others.

Comment: @PieterGoosen SimplePie's working now - it was just getting my head around a new method.